# Nodejs mongodb limit fields with options

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a NodeJS application with MongoDB. I want to combine the following two operations but I am having trouble.

To limit fields to only names:

```js
collection.find({}, {fields: {name:1}}, function(err, cursor){
    res.json(cursor);
});
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        _id: "565c9f1ad5015e516ea99b91",
        name: "Kenneth"
    },
    {
        _id: "5668ea4646175538320c1ad7",
        name: "George"
    }
]
```

To sort values I used:

```
var options = {"sort": "name"}

collection.find({}, options, function(err, cursor){
    res.json(cursor);
});
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        _id: "5668ea4646175538320c1ad7",
        email: "george@gmail.com",
        name: "George"
    },
    {
        _id: "565c9f1ad5015e516ea99b91",
        email: "kenneth@gmail.com",
        name: "Kenneth"
    }
]
```

Essentially I want the following:

```
[
    {
        _id: "5668ea4646175538320c1ad7",
        name: "George"
    },
    {
        _id: "565c9f1ad5015e516ea99b91",
        name: "Kenneth"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine the two options (`fields` and `sort`) into one object:

```
var options = {
    fields: { name: 1 },
    sort: "name"
};

collection.find({}, options, function(err, cursor) {
    res.json(cursor);
});
```